# get a new dataset which is a subset of another dataset and based on some criteria in a column

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, linq, dataset

I have a dataset as follows:

```
foo1, Name, foo2
==================
xxxx, ab01, xxxx
xxxx, ab02, xxxx
xxxx, ab11, xxxx    <---the 1st row of 'ab1%' in Name Column
xxxx, ab12, xxxx
xxxx, ab21, xxxx
xxxx, ab22, xxxx
xxxx, ab31, xxxx
xxxx, ab32, xxxx
xxxx, ab33, xxxx    <---the last row of 'ab3%' in Name Column
xxxx, ab41, xxxx
```

how can I get a new dataset from the above dataset and the column "name" between 'ab1%' and 'ab3%'. That's mean as follows,

```
foo1, Name, foo2
==================
xxxx, ab11, xxxx
xxxx, ab12, xxxx
xxxx, ab21, xxxx  
xxxx, ab22, xxxx
xxxx, ab31, xxxx
xxxx, ab32, xxxx
xxxx, ab33, xxxx
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Hi Eric - have either of the below solutions solved your issue?

Answer (score 0):

You can use like below:

```
var query = from c in DataTableName
where SqlMethods.Like(c.Name, "ab1%") && SqlMethods.Like(c.Name, "ab3%")
select c;
```

---

Answer (score 0):

Just use Linq to query it - this works (although it uses a Regex for the matching!!)  Note the bit that you are most interested in is where I create "dataset2" - this is the *answer* to your question.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var dataset1 = CreateDataSet();
        var regex = new Regex(@"ab[1-3]{1}\d");

        //create dataset
        var oDS = new DataSet();
        var oTable = oDS.Tables.Add();
        oTable.Columns.Add("Foo1", typeof(int));
        oTable.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
        oTable.Columns.Add("Foo2", typeof(int));

        var dataset2 = dataset1.Tables[0].AsEnumerable().Where(x => regex.IsMatch(x["Name"].ToString())).CopyToDataTable();

        foreach (DataRow row in dataset2.Rows)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(row["Name"]);
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static DataSet CreateDataSet()
    {
        //create dataset
        var oDS = new DataSet();
        // create datatable
        var oTable = oDS.Tables.Add();

        //Add coloms
        oTable.Columns.Add("Foo1", typeof(int));
        oTable.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
        oTable.Columns.Add("Foo2", typeof(int));

        //Add rows
        oTable.Rows.Add(1, "ab01", 1);
        oTable.Rows.Add(2, "ab10", 2);
        oTable.Rows.Add(3, "ab11", 3);
        oTable.Rows.Add(4, "ab21", 4);
        oTable.Rows.Add(5, "ab22", 5);
        oTable.Rows.Add(6, "ab31", 6);
        oTable.Rows.Add(7, "ab32", 7);
        oTable.Rows.Add(8, "ab41". 8);

        return oDS;
    }   

}
```